# How to reload tableView data after data is passed by a Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I have two table views. One which the user clicks on and one where data is displayed. When the user clicks on a cell in the first table view a query is made to my firebase database and the query is stored in an Array. I then pass the data through a segue. I used a property observer so I know that the variable is being set. By using break points I was able to determine that my variable obtains its value right before the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I need help displaying the data in my table view. I do not know where to reload the data to get the table view to update with my data. I am using Swift.

EDIT 2: I have solved my problem. I will post my first and second table views so that you can see my solution.

FirstTableView

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class GenreTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let dataBase = FIRDatabase.database()

var genreArray = ["Drama","Classic,Comic/Graphic novel","Crime/Detective","Fable,Fairy tale","Fantasy","Fiction narrative", "Fiction in verse","Folklore","Historical fiction","Horror","Humour","Legend","Magical realism","Metafiction","Mystery","Mythology","Mythopoeia","Realistic fiction","Science fiction","Short story","Suspense/Thriller","Tall tale","Western,Biography","Autobiography","Essay","Narrative nonfiction/Personal narrative","Memoir","Speech","Textbook","Reference book","Self-help book","Journalism", "Religon"]

var ResultArray: [NSObject] = []
var infoArray:[AnyObject] = [] 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return genreArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel?.text = genreArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let DestViewController: ResultTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultTableViewController

    if segue.identifier == "letsGo" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let tappedItem = self.genreArray[indexPath.row]
            DestViewController.someString = tappedItem 
        }  
    }
}
```

}

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ResultTableViewController: UITableViewController {


let dataBase = FIRDatabase.database()
var SecondResultArray: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []
var someString: String?{
    didSet {
      print("I AM A LARGE TEXT")
      print(someString)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let bookRef = dataBase.reference().child("books")

    bookRef.queryOrderedByChild("Genre")
        .queryEqualToValue(someString)
        .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock:{ snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {

                self.SecondResultArray.append(child as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                //print(self.ResultArray)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        })

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return SecondResultArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    let bookSnapShot: FIRDataSnapshot! = self.SecondResultArray[indexPath.row]

    let book = bookSnapShot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

    let Author = book["Author"] as String!
    let Comment = book["Comment"] as String!
    let Genre = book["Genre"] as String!
    let User = book["User"] as String!
    let title = book["title"] as String!

    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Author: " + Author + "\n" + "Comment: " + Comment + "\n" + "Genre: " + Genre + "\n" + "User: " + User + "\n" +  "Title: " + title

    let photoUrl = book["bookPhoto"], url = NSURL(string:photoUrl!), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)

    return cell
}
```

}

For better context and troubleshooting here is my current code for the tableView which is supposed to display data:

```
    import UIKit

    class ResultTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        var SecondResultArray: Array<NSObject> = []{
            willSet(newVal){ 
                print("The old value was \(SecondResultArray) and the new value is \(newVal)")
            }
            didSet(oldVal){
               print("The old value was \(oldVal) and the new value is \(SecondResultArray)")
               self.tableView.reloadData()        
            }
        }
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            print ("I have this many elements\(SecondResultArray.count)")
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }
        // MARK: - Table view data source
        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
            return SecondResultArray.count
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = SecondResultArray[indexPath.row] as? String
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Edit:

Here is my first table view controller. I have tried using the completion handler, but I can't call it correctly and I am constricted by the fact that my query happens in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Please help.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class GenreTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    let dataBase = FIRDatabase.database()

    var genreArray = ["Drama","Classic,Comic/Graphic novel","Crime/Detective","Fable,Fairy tale","Fantasy","Fiction narrative", "Fiction in verse","Folklore","Historical fiction","Horror","Humour","Legend","Magical realism","Metafiction","Mystery","Mythology","Mythopoeia","Realistic fiction","Science fiction","Short story","Suspense/Thriller","Tall tale","Western,Biography","Autobiography","Essay","Narrative nonfiction/Personal narrative","Memoir","Speech","Textbook","Reference book","Self-help book","Journalism", "Religon"]

    var ResultArray: [NSObject] = []
    var infoArray:[AnyObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
       // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

   // MARK: - Table view data source

   override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return genreArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = genreArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    typealias CompletionHandler = (result:NSObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void

    func getData(completionHandeler: CompletionHandler){
        let bookRef = self.dataBase.reference().child("books")
        let GenreSelector = self.genreArray[indexPath.row]
        bookRef.queryOrderedByChild("Genre")
            .queryEqualToValue(GenreSelector)
            .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock:{ snapshot in
                for child in snapshot.children {
                    print("Loading group \((child.key!))")

                    self.ResultArray.append(child as! NSObject)
                }
                print(self.ResultArray)

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("letsGo", sender: self)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
    }
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestViewController: ResultTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultTableViewController
    DestViewController.SecondResultArray = self.ResultArray
}
```

Comment: The property observer can call reloadData

Comment: I think a bit more data will help clarify an answer. Do you have two tableViews in a single viewController or do you have two viewControllers each with a tableView in it? I'm asking because your question says t's your first ViewController but it's defined as a UITableViewController. Also, if the data is being passed correctly, you may not need an observer. Are you using a representedObject variable somewhere?

Comment: I have two tableviews each with their own viewController(in this case each is a UITableViewController.) I'm not sure what a represented Object variable is. My variable called ResultArray has a type of NSObject if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Jay I have solved this problem consistently this time and the results are repeatable. I will be posting the code.

Comment: @TaylorSimpson Now that your code is posted, I know what the issue is. First, avoid dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) when you are working with Firebase. Let Firebase do async calls in it's own way, and present your UI upon those calls returning. However, here's the issue:  *let DestViewController: ResultTableViewController =* in your first controller. What's happening is the DestViewController is going out of scope when that function ends! You need to make your controller variables at the class level so they don't go out of scope. I added another answer for a bit more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

Assume you have an array (myArray) populated from Firebase and stored in the first tableViewController. There's a second tableViewController and a segue connecting them.

We want to be able to tap on an item in the first tableviewController, have the app retrieve detailed data for the item from Firebase (a 'data' node) and display the detailed data in the second tableViewController.

Firebase structure

```
some_node
   child_node_0
     data: some detailed data about child_node_0
   child_node_1
     data: some detailed data about child_node_1
```

Within the second tableViewContoller:

```
var passedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
      self.configView() // Update the view.
     }
}
```

Tapping an item in the first tableView calls the following function

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if segue.identifier == "showListInSecondTable" {
          if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
              let tappedItem = myArray[indexPath.row] as! String
              let keyOfTappedItem = tappedItem.firebaseKey //child_node_0 for example
              doFirebase(keyOfTappedItem)
            }
        }
    }
```

and the prepareForSegue then calls the following which loads the data from firebase and when the snapshot returns within the block, it populates the passedObject property in the second tableView

```
func doFirebase(firebaseKey: String) {

  ref = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("\(firebaseKey)/data")
  //if we want the detailed data for child_node_0 this would resolve
  //  to    rootRef/child_node_0/data
  ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, { snapshot in
     let detailObjectToPass = snapshot.Value["data"] as! NSArray or string etc

     let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).myViewController as! SecondViewController
     controller.passedObject = detailObjectToPass
}
```

and of course in secondController, setting the passedArray calls didSet and sets up the view, and tells the tableView to reload itself, displaying the passed array.

```
func configView() {
   //set up the view and buttons
   self.reloadData()
}
```

I did this super quick so ignore the typos's. The pattern is correct and satisfies the question. (and eliminates the need for an observer to boot!)

P.S. this is way over coded but I wanted to demonstrate the flow and leveraging the asynchronous call to firebase to load the second tableView when the data was valid within the block.

Comment: A minor thing: You need to either ensure you define `func doFirebase(tappedItem:String)` inside `prepareForSegue` or give it the `sender` (or the `SecondViewController` directly) as a parameter. Otherwise it won't fine the segue and can't access the second controller. You can also do `let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController` if the segue is set up correctly, no need to go over the navigation controller (actually that might not work at all).

Comment: should this be `let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).myViewController as! SecondViewController
     controller.passedArray = arrayToPass` instead of `let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).myViewController as! SecondViewController
     controller.passedArray = passedArray`  ?

Comment: I am also a bit confused with the logic. According to your description myArray is the array that stores data from firebase, but in the function you have it storing the data from the item that is clicked, which would be an item from the genreArray.  Also I tried to make arrayToPass to just try your code and it keeps returning nil when being unwrapped. Thank you for your help so far. I get the flow, but the implementation is not working out so far :(

Comment: @TaylorSimpson Yep, just a typo. I added some more info and updated the code a bit to make it more generic. The idea is that when an item is tapped, you get the item details from Firebase and then assign that data to the passedObject property in the second controller so the tableView can access it. Once that assignment has been done, the data is valid and the tableView can be reloaded to display the data. There are still typos but the flow of the data is the important part.

Comment: Would they FirebaseKey be the node I am trying to access?

Comment: @TaylorSimpson Yes. I mention that in the next piece of code   *//if we want the detailed data for child_node_0 this would resolve to rootRef/child_node_0/data*. This is assuming your main array is an array of objects or dictionaries that contains the firebase key as one of it's elements; which is a common design pattern. Keeping that key in the object would enable you to easily update it or get sub data without having to require for the data.

Comment: *requeue for the data, since comments cannot be edited.

Comment: It still will not post to the table, however, your logic looks sound and since you have put so much effort into my question I will award you the bounty.

Comment: @TaylorSimpson I am still curious why it won't. Assuming that you have set up a variable passedObject in your second tableView controller and within that have a didSet message, can you maybe add a print(passedVariable) statement? I want to see if the array that your passing is actually getting stored in the passedVariable. If it's not, we need to look back to the first tableViewController to see why not. If it is, we need to look forward into the second tableViewController to see why the tableView isn't being populated.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the second viewController. I've been trying different things now. I am currently just passing the item that is tapped. Then I make the query in the second view controller. And I am doing it in the cellforRowAtIndexPath method. The query never happens tho. when did set executes it does print out the values, but it happens after everything else.

Comment: @Jay I got it to work! I made the query on the secondTableViewController. I passed the passed item variable to the second view Controller. In the did set method I force the view to reload and the query is executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the data to the destination viewController in `prepareForSegue` Method of the first `UIViewController` and reload your `UITableView` in `viewDidAppear`. If you are getting your data asynchronously, have a completionHandler and reload it in the completionHandler. Here is an example.

```
  func fetchDataWithCompletion(response: (NSDictionary?, error:NSError?)-> Void) -> Void {
    //make the API call here 
    }
```

Comment: Would I call the completion handler in the prepareForSegue Method?

Comment: yes. What a user would expect is that you already be on the second screen when you select a cell on the first screen. So take him to the second screen, show a loading indicator and in the viewDidLoad of your second ViewController, you would fetch for the data required, and hide the loading indicator on the completion call back

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am having trouble getting it right. Can you give me a more in depth example?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your closure to include this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I updated it but, I am not sure how to call the function. It keeps asking for a parameter inside.

Comment: Put it right after self.performSegueWithIdentifier("letsGo", sender: self)

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I meant that I do not know how to call the closure correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

On second read, you *are* already using a completion handler, but I think you didn't see it. Let me correct your code above a bit:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let bookRef = self.dataBase.reference().child("books")
    let GenreSelector = self.genreArray[indexPath.row]
    bookRef.queryOrderedByChild("Genre")
        .queryEqualToValue(GenreSelector)
        .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock:{ snapshot in
            // This here is your completion handler code!
            // I assume it is called asynchronously once your DB is done
            for child in snapshot.children {
                print("Loading group \((child.key!))")

                self.ResultArray.append(child as! NSObject)
            }
            print(self.ResultArray)

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("letsGo", sender: self)
            // self.tableView.reloadData() // is this really needed
        })
    }
}
```

You defined a closure, but simply didn't call it. I don't see a reason for that anyways, assuming the block gets called once the database gives you your results. Am I missing something?

---

That's a good start already, but I think you didn't entirely get how to use a completion handler in this regard, but of course I may be wrong.

I built on top of [user3861282](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3861282/user3861282)'s answer and created a small demo project at [my github](https://github.com/GeroHerkenrath/PrepareSegueIntoCompletionHandler).

In short: You can do all inter-table-communication in the `prepareForSegue:` method of your first table view controller. Configure the second table view controller there (via its vars). Not any closures/completion handlers there yet.

Then in the second view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method, start the loading (including an animation if you want). I suggest something like `NSURLSession` that already defines a completion handler. In that you work with your data from remote, stop any loading animations and you're good.

If the completion handler *must* be defined in the first table view controller, you can even set it as a var in the second table view controller. That way you "hand over" the closure, i.e. "piece of code".

Alternatively, you can start animations and remote request in the first table view controller and then `performSegueWithIdentifier` once that is done. In your question you wrote that you want to load in the second table view controller, however, if I understood you correctly.

---

Your code above properly defines a closure that expects a completion handler (which is also a closure and so kind of doubles what you want), but you never actually call it somewhere. Nor do you call the completion handler in the closure. See my demo for how it can work.

The project I wrote illustrates just one way to do it (minus animations, not enough time). It also shows how you can define your own function expecting a completion handler, but as I said, the standard remote connections in the framework provide one anyways.

Comment: I will be looking at your git hub post in a bit. To answer your edit: I think that block is called when my DB is done. The problem I have been having is passing the information to another table view so that the user can see the results of the query.

Comment: Okay, though my example probably doesn't apply as well as I first thought.

Comment: (Damn, hit enter too soon) I think your DB call above is not called, though: `typealias CompletionHandler = (result:NSObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void` simply defines the type of a closure/block/completionHandler. You actually don't need that. ` func getData(completionHandeler: CompletionHandler){ ... }` defines a closure. You lack `getData { (result, error) in /* your lines of code for the handler go here /* }` to actually invoke it. Basically, you define a function (just in another function, that's what a block/closure is), but you never actually call it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on additional code that was added to the post, the issue is a controller variable going out of scope.

So here's the issue

```
class MyClass {

  func setUpVars {
    let x = 1
  }

  func doStuff {
    print(x)
  }
}
```

Create a class and attempt to print the value of x

```
let aClass = MyClass()
aClass.setUpVars
aClass.doStuff
```

This will print nothing (conceptually) as once setUpVars ended, the 'x' variable went out of scope.

whereas

```
class MyClass {

  var x: Int

  func setUpVars {
    x = 1
  }

  func doStuff {
    print(x)
  }
}
```

will print the value of x, 1.

So the real solution is that your viewControllers need to 'stay alive' during the duration of your class (or app).

Here's the pattern. In the MasterViewController

```
import UIKit

    class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

        var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
```

then in your MasterViewController viewDidLoad (or wherever), create the detailViewController

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let controllers = split.viewControllers //this is from a splitViewController
    self.detailViewController = 
        controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as? DetailViewController
 }
```

and from there you have it... use prepareForSegue to 'send' the data to the detailViewController

Just wanted to have this posted for future reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can reload the TableView with `[tableView reloadData];`.

Comment: I've tried that in various functions through out the tableView controller file, and none of them seem to update the table.