# How to retrieve the array from UITableViewController to ViewTable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'v tried to get array from UITableViewController to another ViewController. I have navigationController and main screen is MyTableViewController. I'm trying to pass data with Segue. Here is the part of MyTableViewController. All other code in this file are correct.

**MyTableViewController**

```swift
    struct Faculty {
        var name = String()
        var descriptions = [String]()
    }
    
    let faculties = [
        Faculty(name: "Faculty of Architecture", descriptions: ["Architecture and Urban Planning", "Spatial Planning"]),
        Faculty(name: "Faculty of Civil Engineering", descriptions: ["Civil Engineering"]),
        Faculty(name: "Faculty of Chemistry", descriptions: ["Biotechnology", "Chemistry","Chemical and Process Engineering", "Materials Science and Engineering", "Chemical Technology"]),
        Faculty(name: "Faculty of Electronics", descriptions: ["Control Engineering and Robotics", "Electronics", "Telecommunications", "Teleinformatics", "Technical Computer Science"])]
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: cell)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail",
           let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            
            let sendDescriptions = faculties[indexPath.row].descriptions
            
            let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController
            destination?.getDescriptions = sendDescriptions
        }
        
        
    }
```

**ViewController**

```swift
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var getDescriptions = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print(getDescriptions)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
        return getDescriptions.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = getDescriptions[row]
        
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: In your question you didn't tell us what the problem is and what the behavior is, but likely your issue is likely duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111704/301525

Comment: Oh sorry, problem is that I sent the array 
```destination?.getDescriptions = sendDescriptions  //I send the selected row of faculty's descriptions, which is an array.
```
And I tried to put the array to tableView but it was empty. So did I initialize getDescription wrong in ViewController?

Comment: Did you debug this and checked if everything in your `prepare(for` function works as expected?